# Constructor injection and method usage

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, constructor

I have a couple of functions I'm rewriting to OOP classes. I'm still very new to OOP and is also using this to learn the basic concepts of OOP.

This is my first class written with the following in mind

- Unit testing/isolation testing
- A class should only do one thing
- Re-usability

This class takes 4 user set variables and tests it against parameters set in the URL, and then returns 4 conditionals, one for every variable set

Here is the class (*I have removed some methods and properties which does the same thing as the `isAuthorReferrer()` method*)

```
namespace PG\Single\Post\Navigation;

/**
 * Test set values against the super global given. Returns conditional properties
 * which is boolean values. true is returned on success and false on failure
 *
 * @param $superGlobalVar Super global to test the values against
 * @param (string) $authorReferrer 
 * @param (string) $dateReferrer 
 * @param (string) $searchReferrer 
 * @param (string) $taxReferrer 
 *
*/ 
class RequestReferrerHandler implements RequestReferrerHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var (array) $superGlobalVar
    */
    protected $superGlobalVar;

    /**
     * @var (bool) $isAuthorReferrer
    */
    protected $isAuthorReferrer;

    //OTHER PROPERTIES

    /**
     * Public constructor method
     *
     * @param $SuperGlobalVar  Super global to get data from
    */
    public function __construct($superGlobalVar = null, $authorReferrer= null, $dateReferrer = null, $searchReferrer = null, $taxReferrer = null )
    {
        /**
         * Properties
         */
        $this->superGlobalVar = $superGlobalVar;
        $this->authorReferrer = $authorReferrer;
        $this->dateReferrer   = $dateReferrer;
        $this->searchReferrer = $searchReferrer;
        $this->taxReferrer    = $taxReferrer;

        /**
         * Conditional methods, all returns boolean values
         */
        $this->isAuthorReferrer();
        //etc
    }

    /**
     * Test $authorReferrer against $superGlobalVar
     *
     * @return (bool) true on success or false on failure
     */
    public function isAuthorReferrer()
    {
        if ($this->authorReferrer && isset($this->superGlobalVar[$this->authorReferrer])) { 
            $isAuthorReferrer = true;
        } else {
            $isAuthorReferrer = false;
        }
        return $this->isAuthorReferrer = $isAuthorReferrer;
    }

    //OTHER METHODS, SAME AS isAuthorReferrer() METHOD

    /**
     * Returns an array of super global variables
     * @return (array) $this->getRequest
    */ 
    public function getSuperGlobalVar()
    {
        return $this->superGlobalVar;
    }

}
```

I have read some posts that said you should make use of constructor injection, so have written my class around that.

I do have a few concerns here, one being instantiating my methods in the constructor

### MY TEST

```
$a = new PG\Single\Post\Navigation\RequestReferrerHandler($_GET, 'aq', 'dq', 'sq', 'tq');
?><pre><?php var_dump($a); ?></pre><?php
```

With the code above, I get the following output

```
object(PG\Single\Post\Navigation\RequestReferrerHandler)#496 (9) {
  ["superGlobalVar":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tq"]=>
    string(10) "category 1"
  }
  ["isAuthorReferrer":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["isDateReferrer":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["isSearchReferrer":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["isTaxReferrer":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["authorReferrer"]=>
  string(2) "aq"
  ["dateReferrer"]=>
  string(2) "dq"
  ["searchReferrer"]=>
  string(2) "sq"
  ["taxReferrer"]=>
  string(2) "tq"
}
```

If I remove my methods from the constructor, my four conditional properties returns `NULL`, but I do get the correct boolean values if I call the methods directly like

```
?><pre><?php var_dump($a->isAuthorReferrer()); ?></pre><?php
```

The results from the `var_dump()` is:

if `aq` is set

```
bool(true)
```

if `aq` is not set

```
bool(false)
```

### MY QUESTION

Am I using the methods correctly in the constructor and is my class even correctly set up

Comment: what's the output of var_dump($a->isAuthorReferrer());??

Comment: @noob I have updated my question with those specifics

Comment: so it's exactly working as expected what's the prob?

Comment: Yes,  my question is, am I using the methods correctly in my constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of a constructor is to create the object after which the methods can be applied. Besides the goal of the constructor is another compelling reason that the constructor must be able to end without any problem or the construction of the object might fail causing a memory leak. Therefor is it not a good OOP design to call methods within the constructor. 
Furthermore are you making it more difficult to extend or even change the design of a class in which methods are called within a constructor. The construction of an object will be dependent on the availability of methods it should precede. 
I prefer an init-method to call the methods you would like to execute before the rest of the code. When I want to load a configfile I set it in the constructor and read it in the init-method.

Comment: So, practically it would be best to completely remove my methods from my constructor

Comment: Yep. You can ask yourself what are the best default values of your booleans and give them those values.